# Am I understanding refreshToken on Firebase correctly?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, streamlit

This is what I'm doing in a python Streamlit project using Firebase (more specifically using the [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) wrapper:

- Have the user login/signup which returns a `user` object
- Save the `refreshToken` as a cookie
- The next time the user arrives on the webpage, I use the refreshToken from cookie to request another refresh token and get the `user` object, so they don't have to log in again.

I have the following concerns:

1. Is this approach a good practice?
2. Does this mean that basically anyone who has access to the users's `refreshToken` can log in as them? So as long as I'm storing it as a cookie, I should be fine. Right?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to request a refresh token every time the user visits your webpage — they only expire when a user is deleted, disabled, or something big about the user account changes (e.g. a password change). However, you can use the refresh token to retrieve a new Firebase ID token (which expire after an hour) and include it in a request to your backend, which should extract the ID token and use it to verify your user's identity. Take a look at the [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) for more information.
2. Yes — you can revoke refresh tokens if you have reason to believe that it has been compromised.